# how to fetch Heart Rate Googlefit?

Tags: android, google-fit, heartrate

Now I am implementing googlefit in my android application. I can not find any proper documentation for fetching heart rate. Please help me to fetch heart rate data from googlefit sdk/api.

Answer (score 0):

if you're primarily relying on Fit's aggregation type called "Heart Points", then you can have this within your aggregate request body :

```
{
"aggregateBy": [
    {
        "dataTypeName": "com.google.heart_minutes",
        "dataSourceId": "derived:com.google.heart_minutes:com.google.android.gms:merge_heart_minutes"
    }
],
"bucketByTime": {
    "durationMillis": 86400000 //bucketed in a day
},
"startTimeMillis": //insert your start time in millis,
"endTimeMillis": //insert your end time in millis
}
```

But if you really want to pull raw Heart Rate datapoints, you can execute it using this body instead :

```
{
"aggregateBy": [
    {
        "dataTypeName": "com.google.heart_rate.bpm",
        "dataSourceId": "derived:com.google.heart_rate.bpm:com.google.android.gms:merge_heart_rate_bpm"
    }
],
"bucketByTime": {
    "durationMillis": 8640000 //bucketed in a day
},
"startTimeMillis": //insert your start time in millis,
"endTimeMillis": //insert your end time in millis 
}
```

I recommend that you familiarise yourself with the Fit system architecture, especially with querying what datasource are available for the types you would like to query.